# Create other enviroment error in node?

Tags: node.js

I have a settings-module in a node app, that changes settings based on the environment.

```
var settings,
    environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;

if(environment === 'developments'){
    settings = {
        facebookCredentials: {
            clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
            callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/facebook/callback"
        }
    };
}else if(environment === 'production'){
   //here goes live settings.
}else{
  //this is where the error goes.
}
exports.settings = settings;
```

If the enviroment-name is something else, I now get an error about the a setting being undefined, instead, I want to log some sort of error about an invalid NODE_ENV name. How could I do this? I'm new to node, is there an overall better design for handling environment specific settings?

Comment: You could establish one environment as the default – `if (environment == 'production') { ... } else { /* development */ }` or the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches here:

1. Use [`console.error`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_error_data) to log your error
2. Throw an actual error in your `else` block: `throw new Error('Invalid Environment Specified')`

I personally would prefer option 2, since invalid configuration is something that you want to fail fast and explicitly.

Also, there are plenty of modules out there to help manage configuration [nconf](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf) being a popular one.